# How to use JSON generator to create object within array

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, integration

I have one JSON format

```
   {
  "request": {
    "key": "NC",
    "msgId": "XXXXXX",
    "sourceSystem": "Salesforce",
    "targetSystem": "test",
    "objectName": "Notifcation",
    "payload": {
      "to": "XXXXXXX",
      "messageBody": "XXXXX",
      "userType": "XXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to use JSON generator class to create something like this

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner to use the various `serialize` methods of the [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm). Also, feeding the JSON into https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ that generates code for your is often a good choice.

Your example JSON doesn't include any arrays; arrays are delimited by `[...]` - see e.g. https://www.json.org/json-en.html.